# Error:Attribute "android:orientation" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, viewpagerindicator

I have added "viewpagerindicator" library and "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0" as a dependance in my project . Both of them has declare 'orientation' attribute
in 'viewpagerindicator' library its written -

```
<declare-styleable name="CirclePageIndicator">
        <attr name="android:orientation"> 
    </declare-styleable>
```

I am getting the above error how I can resolve this.

Comment: try inherit orientation property using parent.

Comment: You will probably need to fork and modify the relevant ViewPagerIndicator library classes and resources to rename the attribute to `vpi_orientation` or some such.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks for replying.But I am not able to redefine <attr name="android:orientation"> .  how can I change this "android:orientation" as it seems that it is using the default android orientation. Please explain with an example.

Comment: @HareshChhelana : can you please give an example. As I have tried but not able to do it. :(

Comment: which is top most parent library viewpagerindicator or com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0?

Comment: @HareshChhelana: They are not related to each other. I am using both of them in my project for different purposes.

Comment: Can you show us how do you actually use this attribute? Looks like you are not using it right.

Comment: I am not using this attribute.I want to add these two libraries as a dependency in my project.

Comment: @niteshgoel: I don't think that you can have such error just because of using both library at a time. Even though if you insist, you may remove the line `<attr name="android:orientation"> ` and check if it works fine for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use at build.gradle

```
compile 'fr.baloomba:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2'
```

See more details at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.baloomba/viewpagerindicator/2.4.2

Comment: how it is different from the original one?

Comment: according https://github.com/baloomba/Android-ViewPagerIndicator there was added gradle implementation. I tried to build empty project with your 2 dependencies at Android Stuiod . 2.4.1 gained error, 2.4.2 did not.

Comment: still not working getting the same error . /build/intermediates/exploded-aar/fr.baloomba/viewpagerindicator/2.4.2/res/values/values.xml Error:Attribute "orientation" has already been defined

Comment: Looks like you need to provide more details here, version of used AS, full version of your `build.gradle` and output from `gradlew androidDependencies` command.

Comment: I guess that won't work .Today I updated my AS. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

With this .gradle build successfully for me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cooperbros.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}   

dependencies {

  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0'
  compile 'fr.baloomba:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2'

}
```