# Android v7 gridlayout library, impossible to build the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, android-gridlayout

I have a big project with few dependencies and I want to add the v7 gridlayout support library too, but after that, i cant build my project anymore.

Adding the library in build.gradle like this (I use Android Studio 1.5.1) :

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0'
```

Sync project working, but after that i cant find `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` and when i try to build my project I have the following error :

```
C:\Users\jgully\AndroidStudioProjects\swingmobile\SwingMobileEngine\res\values\colors.xml
 > Error:(2) Attribute "orientation" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':SwingMobileEngine:processReleaseResources'.
 > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\jgull\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

So I suspect a attribute declared twice in two different dependecies but i dont know how i can fix that.

I have find a similiar problem here with viewpagerindicator: [Error:Attribute "android:orientation" has already been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169255/errorattribute-androidorientation-has-already-been-defined)

*colors.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="blue_light">#2D9DC8</color>
<color name="blue_dark">#314d61</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="green_light">#308A24</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="black_light">#333</color>
<color name="grey_light">#A1A1A1</color>
<color name="red">#C20031</color>
<color name="green_dark">#496948</color>
<color name="grey">#363636</color>
<color name="grey_dark">#424242</color>
<color name="grey_dark_alpha_50">#88424242</color>

<color name="vpi__background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
<color name="vpi__background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_holo_dark">@color/vpi__background_holo_light</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_holo_light">@color/vpi__background_holo_dark</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_dark">#ff4c4c4c</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_disabled_holo_light">#ffb2b2b2</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_inverse_holo_dark">
    @color/vpi__bright_foreground_holo_light
</color>
<color name="vpi__bright_foreground_inverse_holo_light">
    @color/vpi__bright_foreground_holo_dark
</color>

<!-- To override values in legacy projects (if needed) -->
<color name="dialog_default_text_color">#ffffff</color>
<color name="dialog_default_background_color">#000000</color>

<!-- end of to override values in legacy projects (if needed) -->

<!-- Listview gray divider -->
<drawable name="listview_graydivider">#CCCCCC</drawable>

<!-- Gradient values (Default is SWB) -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_firstcolor">#868686</color>
<!-- FFA938 -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_secondcolor">#a5a5a5</color>
<!-- FFAF47 -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_thirdcolor">#5b5b5b</color>
<!-- D4831A -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_fourthcolor">#727272</color>
<!-- F29729 -->

<color name="default_dialog_gradient_dark_firstcolor">#222222</color>
<!-- A97025 -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_dark_secondcolor">#2b2b2b</color>
<!-- A9732E -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_dark_thirdcolor">#181818</color>
<!-- B55711 -->
<color name="default_dialog_gradient_dark_fourthcolor">#1e1e1e</color>
<!-- 9F6314 -->
```

*All dependecies of the project*

- Zxing
- pdfview
- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0
- itextpdf-5.3.2
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87
- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2

*note : im not the author of the begin of this project and i dont know where some lib is used*

Comment: another lib that you import is declaring that attribute as well. post the list of your dependencies.

Comment: Seems like there is some problem in `colors.xml`. Update the answer with some code.

Comment: I added the colors.xml code but no orientation attribut here :(. I add all depedencies on the end of the post.

Comment: You are most likely over 65536 methods. Do not include the entire Play Services library, only its relevant parts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27366164/2413303 then you probably won't need multidex support either.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, like I said upper, im not the first developper on this project and I dont have been played with Play services beforce. But sadly, this don't fix my problem.